# In Marketing Cloud, I want to test whether bcc is working or not for all Triggered Sends in my BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

We have enabled the CC and as well BCC feature for all trigger sends for MyJD as well as John Deere BU’s. Now I want to test it. I did that but getting following message:

> A problem occurred Updating the Triggered Send.  Please contact
>   Customer Service for additional information. Name :
>   myJD_forgot_username_trigger External Key : 12345  Message : The email
>   ID = 67891, contained 2 validation errors. Refer to the Triggered Send
>   Email Validation error log, ID = 983040314.

Comment: It means that there is an error in your emails logic. Should have nothing to do with BCC. Best bet is to do a send preview on the email using test data for more info on errors. Also I would verify that your TSD is using the most recent version of your email (publish changes)

Comment: Thank you. CC/BCC field updated in Triggered Sends. Now, I want to validate/test if the emails are getting CC/bcc’ed or not. Need someone who is familiar with testing scenarios in Triggered Sends/Marketing Cloud. Thanks.!!

Comment: The error in your question has nothing to do with BCC/CC. Once you fix those errors in your email, you can run test sends of your TSD and verify that the BCC/CC are also receiving the emails.